# Privatemsg with user_relationships - views link → send a private message to use

Tags: users, privatemsg

Trying to output Views link - send a private message to a user. But its displaying nothing. Using privatemsg 6.x - 2.x Dev version and user_relationships 6.x - 1.x

Answer (score 1):

solved problem with the code below:

```
<?php
$profile = content_profile_load('profile', $data->users_user_relationships_uid);
$url = privatemsg_get_link(array(user_load($profile->uid)));
print '<div class="pm">'. l(t('Send a private message to the author'), $url, array('attributes' => array('class' => 'lichnoe'))) .'</div>'; 
?>
```

Comment: Used Views Custom field: PHP